# Why is the logged in user not detected with 'user.is_authenticated' in my template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication

In my template I have

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/">Logout</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

which adds a button to the nav bar if the user is logged in. the code works for all the views that have @login_required or @permission_required  but it doesn't recognize the user if they travel a page that allows but logged in users and anonymous users. Any idea why why this is and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have:

```
django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth
```

your context processors in `settings.py`, and you need to pass

```
RequestContext
```

to the view, in order to have `user` in your context.